# What is the noun for "encoding"?

Tags: nouns

I am currently writing a paper about how neurons encode a stimuli. We would like a noun for the process of encoding, something like "encodement". However, I am not sure whether this is the best choice. Any ideas?

Comment: "Encoding" is what I'd use.

Comment: The noun for encoding is *encoding*.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! I like the "encoding". Can't believe that I didn't think about the most obvious solution :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's **"the encoding"** :-)

See at Google Books:

["the encoding is performed"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22the%20encoding%20for%20this%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22the%20encoding%20is%20performed%22)

What is performed is a "process."

Sometimes specialized names are used:

> [Semisupervised learning in computational linguistics](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hs5oAAAAIAAJ&q=%22the%20encoding%20is%20called%22&dq=%22the%20encoding%20is%20called%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iEkkVZP2L8TfsAS6aQ&ved=0CEcQ6AEwCQ) - Page 65
>    Steven P. Abney - 2008
>
> If classifiers make uncorrelated errors, and codewords are maximally
>   distant from one another, the encoding method is robust to errors made
>   by the individual classifiers. **The encoding is called an
>   Error-Correcting Output Code (ECOC)**;

Answer (score 0):

[*Encodement* is the nounal form of *encoding*.](http://wordhippo.com/what-is/the-noun-for/encode.html)

Comment: I wonder if this is regional as I've never heard or read "encodement" used and I work in software development where this concept is talked about a lot. (but you can certainly find "encodement" in the dictionary) Context: I'm American - lived there for 4 decades and have now lived in Germany for 6 years.

Comment: Similarly, am Australian, have worked in software for years, have lived in other countries, and never heard or read encodement until today.

Comment: @AdamBurke, the reason that thou hath not heard the term used before I mentioned it is likely to be because many people prefer to use gerunds rather than the adjective and noun form(s) of many words.

Comment: That may indeed be, but extremely rare usage should still be flagged as such, too. Encodement is such a rare usage that it should be flagged as rare or archaic, and avoided in most everyday use.